# Is it possible to determinate at run time is pointer points to C++ class or at Objective-C class?

Tags: c++, objective-c, pointers, objective-c++, delete-operator

Question is in subject.

I want to write some universal template function for safe deleting objects and wondering is it possible to use something like this:

```
template< class T > void SafeDelete( T*& pVal )
{
    if(objc_is_cpp_object(pVal)){
        delete pVal;
        pVal = NULL;
    }
    else
        [pVal release]
}
```

Comment: Why you want to use same function name for different languages ? Why can't you distinguish them by using a different name ?

Comment: C++ `delete` and Obj-C `release` mean quite different things; conflating the two seems like a questionable idea at best.

Comment: I thought about different name first then I just feel curiously about its it possible to have a same question for both languages. And then I thought that it might be not very good idea though, but still feelt curiously :-) So this is mostly theoretical question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, I would suggest not to mix the C++ `delete` and Objective-C `release`.
Just for technical point of view, you can use the following SFINAE trick runtime:

```
template<typename T> struct void_ { typedef void type; };

template<typename, typename = void>
struct CppType { static const bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct CppType<T, typename void_<int (T::*)>::type> { static const bool value = true; };

template< class T > 
void SafeDelete( T*& pVal )
{
  if(CppType<T>::value || std::is_pod<T>::value) {  // <-----
    delete pVal;
    pVal = 0;
  }   
  else {
     // [pVal release];
  }   
}
```

Possibly, `is_pod` is available in C++11, boost etc. But it's easy to implement.

Comment: Can you explain what means "typename void_<int (T::*)>::type" ? As far I understand idea is that this string in case of objc object will be substituted by void type and specialized version of template will return false; But can't understand how this happens still. Thank you.

Comment: @andrey.s, this mechanism is called SFINAE. `int (T::*)` means the pointer to member variable. Now, pointer to member is possible only for C++ `class` or `union` and not for any other entity. Thus, if a given type is a C++ `class` type then `CppType<T>::value` will be `true` and you can perform C++ specific tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C pointers are the same as C++ pointers: 4-to-8 word integer values that point to various objects in memory. The Objective-C compiler supports outputting values in with multiple formats, such as C, C++, and Objective-C object layouts.

That's it. There really isn't much beyond that.

You can try to do something hacky like create a class where a field always contains a magic value:

```
template <class T>
class Magic {
    private:
        const char magic[] = 1234567;
    public:
        bool is_object() const {
            return magic == 1234567;
        }
}
```

then you could test it like so:

```
bool is_cpp(void *ptr) {
    return ((Magic*) ptr)->is_object();
}
```

But be forewarned that this is *extremely* hacky.

Comment: Your suggestion is using base "Magic" class for all cpp objects?

Comment: that's the general idea. again, this is not something you want to do in production, because no values are special...

Comment: Objective-C comes with this magic: all objective-c pointer addressees are of type `struct objc_object`, whose (albiet private) definition idiomatically must contain an `isa_t isa` member … while I dunno about runtime inspection, I personally found `objc_object::isa` quite good enough for SFINAE e.g. `objc::traits::is_object<T>`; see: http://git.io/vCsLa – Further reading: http://unixjunkie.blogspot.de/2006/02/nil-and-nil.html plus the objc runtime source – http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-647/runtime/objc-private.h